# fade out, fade in new div when click outside div

Tags: jquery, html, fadein, children

I've got page with jQuery that does the following, and I will need help with the last step:

The page contains the div (#"containerSW") which switches its content back and forth when a button (#"doit") is pressed.

The content of 'containerSW' are two divs ('div1' and 'div2') that contain images. These images will function as buttons that load an entirely new div (#"containerprA") in the place of parent div 'containerSW' (see input of first image in 'div1').

So far everything works, except now I'm trying to make a click function that fades out 'containerprA to go back to 'containerSW', when you click outside of 'containerprA'. I've attempted to do this with the mouseup function below, but can't get 'containerSW' to fade in: it appears too fast on the page.

I think the problem lies in the children divs of 'containerSW', but I'm not sure how to solve it ..

the html:

```
<input id="doit" type="image" src="Img/array_arrow_rightII.jpg" height=120px width 40px   value="clickme">


<div id="containerSW">
<div id="div1">
    <img class="SW">
    <input id="loadprA" type="image" src="Img/SW_A.jpg" height=125px width 125px >
    <img src="Img/SW_B.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
    <img src="Img/SW_C.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
    <img src="Img/SW_D.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
</div>
<div id="div2">
    <img class="SW">
    <img src="Img/SW_E.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
    <img src="Img/SW_F.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
    <img src="Img/SW_G.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
    <img src="Img/SW_H.jpg" height=125px width 125px>
</div>
</div>

<div id="containerprA" class="hidden">

<img src="Img/SW_divtester.jpg" height=150px width=400 >

</div>
```

The css:

```
#div1 {
}
#div2 {
    display: none;
}
.hidden {
    display:none;
    background-color:red;
}
#containerprA {
    height:400px; 
    width:800px;
    background-color: blue;
}
```

The script:

```
$(function () {
var vis = 1;
$('#doit').click(function () {
    $('#containerSW').fadeOut('slow', function () {
        $('#div'+vis).hide();
        vis = vis === 1 ? 2 : 1;
        $('#div'+vis).show();
        $('#containerSW').fadeIn('slow');
    });
})
});

$(function(){
$('#loadprA').click(function(){
    $('#containerprA').hide();
    $('#containerSW').fadeOut('slow', function() {
    $('#containerprA').removeClass('hidden');
    $('#containerprA').fadeIn('slow');


    });
})
});


$(document).mouseup(function (e)
{
var container = $('#containerprA');
var containerSW = $('#containerSW');


if (!container.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && container.has(e.target).length === 0); // ... nor a descendant of the container

if (!containerSW.is(e.target) // if the target of the click isn't the container...
    && containerSW.has(e.target).length === 0) // ... nor a descendant of the container

{
    container.fadeOut('slow');
    containerSW.fadeIn('slow');
}

});
```

Any help regarding this last step would be really great.!

Answer (score 0):

Use the callback. This will make sure the fade in starts only when the fadeout ends.

```
container.fadeOut('slow',function(){
containerSW.fadeIn('slow');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use the entire page as a target, and check if it is "not" the `containerprA` ..

```
$('body,html').on('click', function(e) {

  if( !$(e.target).is( $('#containerprA, #containerprA *') ) ){
    // your logic here
  }

});
```

Basically this says if we clicked on anything that is not #containerprA then do something.
http://jsfiddle.net/simeydotme/X49Ku/